TKinter how to do a conversion
Ive been trying to turn degree celsius into fahrenheit and kelvin, but Im new to Tkinter and havent been able to find someone to explain how it does mathematical processes to return the degrees in the new scale, also because It would be too nice to just ask this the code has some spanish in it, im just gonna leave it there, hope someone is able to understand it
    import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Conversor de grados')
root.geometry('400x500')
root.resizable(False,False)


 name_label = tk.Label(
 root,
 text = 'Convertir a ºF y K',
 font = ('Arial', 200 ),
 bg = 'blue',
 fg = '#FF0' )


number_label = tk.Label(
    root,
    text = '¿Que temperatura hace?'
    )
number_input = tk.Entry(root)
#number_input = grados introducidos
value = number_input



submit_button1 = tk.Button (root, text = 'convertir a ºF')
output_line = tk.Label(root)
submit_button2 = tk.Button (root, text = 'convertir a K')
output_line = tk.Label(root)

number_label.pack()
number_input.pack()


submit_button1.pack()
submit_button2.pack()

output_line.pack()

def resultadof():
    f = int((value*9/5)+32)
    
def on_submit1():
        """Cuado se pulse el botón"""
         print "resultadof"
            
        
            
        output_line.configure(text=message)
        
def on_submit2():
        """Cuado se pulse el botón"""
    
        number = number_input.get()
    
   
   
        resultadof=(number*9/5)+32
        
        message = (
            f'son {number_input} grados.\n'
        
            )
        output_line.configure(text=message)


if submit_button1.configure(command = on_submit1):
   submit_button2.configure(command = on_submit2)

root.mainloop()

---

- Im trying to turn celsius into kelvin and fahrenheit through tk, i tried using buttons as it seamed the easiest, I wasnt able, the program should just return the degrees on the scale you choose



I have edited your code and used English.
import tkinter as tk

Firstly, I created 2 functions that calculate celsius to Fahrenheit and Celsius to kelvin. Both have parameters named Celsius.
def celsius_to_fahrenheit(celsius):
    fahrenheit = (celsius * 9/5) + 32
    return fahrenheit

def celsius_to_kelvin(celsius):
    kelvin = celsius + 273.15
    return kelvin

convert_temperature is a command function for convert_button. It basically gets value from number_input and checks selected_scale.After that run the calculation functions that I mentioned above, depending on them. After calculation, it will update output_line.
def convert_temperature():
    try:
        celsius = float(number_input.get())
        if selected_scale.get() == "Fahrenheit":
            result = celsius_to_fahrenheit(celsius)
            unit = "°F"
        elif selected_scale.get() == "Kelvin":
            result = celsius_to_kelvin(celsius)
            unit = "K"
        else:
            result = "Error: Select a scale"
            unit = ""
        output_line.config(text=f"{result:.2f} {unit}")
    except ValueError:
        output_line.config(text="Invalid input. Enter a number.")

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Temperature Converter')  
root.geometry('400x200')

name_label = tk.Label(
    root,
    text='Convert to °F and K', 
    font=('Arial', 16),  
    bg='blue',
    fg='#FF0'
)
name_label.pack()

number_label = tk.Label(
    root,
    text='Enter temperature in Celsius:'  
)
number_label.pack()

number_input = tk.Entry(root)
number_input.pack()

selected_scale = tk.StringVar()
selected_scale.set("Select scale") 

scale_options = ["Fahrenheit", "Kelvin"]
scale_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(root, selected_scale, *scale_options)
scale_dropdown.pack()

convert_button = tk.Button(root, text="Convert", command=convert_temperature)
convert_button.pack()

output_line = tk.Label(root)
output_line.pack()

root.mainloop()


thank you for your time, I was strugling to use the value inside the if as I didnt exactly know the comands, and I have observed the great use you do with the scale options, makes it cleaner and easier to work with.

I'm happy to hear that. If you have any questions feel free to ask me
